How can I use rclone unattended while protecting my access keys from my provider?
I am running rclone remotely, over SSH, in the form of:
ssh user@host rclone ...

And this means that I have an rclone config at that host that contains my S3 bucket credentials--which I do not want my provider to see.
How can I run this remote rclone command--unattended from my crontab--in a way that my rclone host does not have access to my credentials/secrets/keys ?
I cannot set environment variables at the remote host.
I am aware that there is a way to run rclone without a config file, with all of the config options specified in one big long string of command line options....but then I think the remote system would see my credentials in the process table with 'ps' command.
I also think there is a way to encrypt the remote config file so that it cannot be inspected on the remote host....but then I am not sure how I can run my:
ssh user@host rclone ...

command unattended from a cron job since nobody is there to key in a decrypt passphrase.
How can I do this?

I'm not sure you can. What I do is create an IAM user with a very restricted permissions policy that only lets it write to that one S3 bucket - no access to other buckets, no delete access, etc.
